# Lettuce BDD : How to refer scenarios?

Tags: python, bdd, lettuce

I am using Lettuce BDD framework for python, and I am wondering how to run one scenario from within another scenario..

For example, say there is a "registration" scenario that establishes some pre-conditions which will be used by a subsequent scenario (say "action" scenario") - how do I refer and call the "registration" scenario from "action" scenario?

Comment: try this tutorial it might be of help to you http://www.blog.fruiapps.com/2012/11/Behavior-Driven-Development-in-Python-with-Lettuce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "behave_as" feature for Lettuce which should do this.  Though there were some bugs with it last time I tried to use it.  May be fixed now.  I opened a bug on it with Gabriel, the author.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some lettuce research and came across this older question.

It looks like the preferred way to handle this is to change the scope of the reuseable method by using the decorator "@world.absorb" when declaring the method
this attributes the method to the world object and allows it to be called.  You can then call the world.*yourAction* from your other method

there's a thorough explanation on the yipit blog written by Gabriel:

http://tech.yipit.com/2011/12/23/lettuce-best-and-worst-practices-1/

Like i said, I'm just learning lettuce, so if anybody has found an even better/newer way to accomplish this, please let me know!